Wechsel von Indikativ zu Konjunktiv in einem Satz
Dieser folgende Wechsel vom Indikativ zum Konjunktiv scheint für mein Sprachempfinden in Ordnung zu sein:

Aristoteles zufolge existiert die Welt schon immer. Dies sei so, weil
sich die Welt in einem ewigen Zyklus des Entstehens und Vergehens
befinde.

Für mein Sprachempfinden wäre es hier auch übertrieben, zu schreiben: "Aristoteles zufolge existiere...", weil das quasi doppelt gemoppelt wäre.
Wie ist es jetzt aber, wenn man die Sätze zusammenzieht:

Aristoteles zufolge existiert die Welt schon immer, weil sie sich in
einem ewigen Zyklus des Entstehens und Vergehens befinde.

Kann man innerhalb des Satzes einen solchen Wechsel vollziehen, um im letzteren Teil zu verdeutlichen, dass man die Aussage nicht unbedingt teilt (während das beim vorderen Teil klar ist) oder muss man dann den ganzen Satz im Indikativ bzw. Konjunktiv formulieren?

"Können" kann man viel, ob man "sollte", ist immer ein bißchen eine andere Frage - Für mich hört sich dein Beispiel komisch an.

Man kann nicht nur, man muß den weil-Satz sogar im Konjunktiv schreiben, wenn man sich die Ansicht, die Welt befinde sich in einem ewigen Zyklus pp., nicht zu eigen machen will.

Man muss den "weil"-Teil im Konjunktiv schreiben. Man muss die beiden Sätze aber nicht zusammenziehen.

Bei den ersten beiden Sätzen wird im zweiten Satz der Konjunktiv verwendet, um eine indirekte Rede zu kennzeichnen. Wenn du das zusammenziehst, brauchst du die indirekte Rede nicht mehr: Der Nebensatz bezieht sich ja auf den Hauptsatz. Daher musst du dann den Indikativ verwenden. Dass es dabei im Nebensatz nicht um deine Meinung geht, sagt ja schon der Hauptsatz.

Halten wir zunächst fest: der Konjunktiv hat (unter anderem, aber der Rest ist hier nicht von Belang) die Aufgabe, indirekte Rede zu kennzeichnen:

Er sagt: "Ich will."
Er sagt, er wolle.

So weit, so allgemein bekannt. Nun stellt sich die Frage, welcher Teil des obigen Texts überhaupt eine indirekte Rede darstellt. Kommen wir zum ersten Satz:

Aristoteles zufolge existiert die Welt schon immer.

Wenn das indirekte Rede sein sollte, dann müßte Aristoteles erstens irgendwo den Satz:

"Die Welt existiert schon immer."

gesagt oder geschrieben haben. (Ich werde im folgenden immer "gesagt" sagen, auch wenn ich von Geschriebenem rede.) Außerdem dürfte der Satz nicht mit "Aristoteles zufolge" eingeleitet werden, denn das zeigt ja an, daß das was da folgt, ja nicht die Nachricht, was er gesagt hat, sondern die Zusammenfassung dessen, was er meint ist, in der - eigenständigen(!) - Wiedergabe desjenigen, der den Satz sagt.
Aristoteles hat also vielleicht das gesagt:

Ich glaube also, daß die Welt niemals angefangen hat, sondern vielmehr, daß sie schon in allerfernster Vergangenheit da war.

und der, der uns was darüber erzählt, faßt das nun zusammen mit dem Satz

Aristoteles zufolge existiert die Welt schon immer.

Solche Zusammenfassungen sind durchaus legitim, aber man darf sie nicht als Wiedergabe von etwas Gesagtem ausgeben, sondern muß sie als das kennzeichnen, was sie sind: Interpretation.
Kommen wir zum zweiten Satz:

Dies sei so, weil sich die Welt in einem ewigen
Zyklus des Entstehens und Vergehens befinde.

Auch das wäre nur dann indirekte Rede, wenn der Satz genau so, im Indikativ, irgendwo im aristotelischen Korpus zu finden wäre:

Die Welt befindet sich in einem ewigen Zyklus des Entstehens und Vergehens.

vielleicht auch:

Dies ist so, weil sich die Welt in einem ewigen Zyklus des Entstehens und Vergehens befindet.

Aber wenn das nicht der Fall ist - und, ohne das gesamte Oeuvre Aristoteles' im Kopf zu haben, gehe ich davon aus, daß sich dieser Satz so nirgendwo findet - dann ist auch das keine indirekte Rede, sondern eine Zusammenfassung von A.s Standpunkt.
Das als indirekte Rede zu formulieren und damit Herrn Aristoteles Worte in den Mund zu legen, die er so nie gesagt hat, wäre unredlich. Denn die Zusammenfassung kann richtig sein oder auch nicht, sie kann A.s Standpunkt korrekt wiedergeben oder auch nicht, aber immer bleibt sie Interpretation und damit nicht Wiedergabe. Es ist ein Unterschied zwischen "A hat gesagt" und "ich habe A so verstanden".
Wenn das aber alles keine indirekte Rede ist, dann hat auch der Konjunktiv nirgendwo was verloren. Dann muß die erste Version lauten:

Aristoteles zufolge existiert die Welt schon immer.
Dies ist so, weil sich die Welt in einem ewigen
Zyklus des Entstehens und Vergehens befindet.

Die zweite Version (die ich bevorzugen würde, weil sie viel klarer als Zusammenfassung des aristotelischen Standpunkts auftritt) muß dann lauten:

Aristoteles zufolge existiert die Welt schon immer,
weil sie sich in einem ewigen Zyklus des Entstehens
und Vergehens befindet.

